# Filter Condition With EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

I have found that you can use this syntax to filter a workbook with EPPlus `range.AutoFilter = true;`

But I have not seen if/how I can pass in a filter parameter.    For example, using the Excel Interop - I would use

```
range.AutoFilter(1, range.Cells[2, 1].Value);
```

Does EPPlus have the equivalent of such?

**EDIT**
What I am after here is the ability to copy all rows (including headers) from a master worksheet to sub-worksheets.

For example, if the master worksheet looks like this

```
Name   A   B   C   D
Joe    XX  XX  XX  XX
Joe    XX  XX  XX  XX
Joe    XX  XX  XX  XX
Jack   AA  AA  AA  AA
Jack   AA  AA  AA  AA
Jim    BB  BB  BB  BB
```

The steps I would need to occur are

> 1) Create a new worksheet, name it Joe
>   
> 2) Copy all data for Joe (including headers to new worksheet)
>   
> 3) Repeat process for all names in the list

**I have this working with Excel Interop, but of course using this course is SLOW!**

Comment: Generally, no, Epplus does not have the ability to apply native excel filters - it just generates raw xml.  Best you can do is mimic the filter in code.  See if this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398255/create-advanced-filter/33412586#33412586  or this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723483/adding-a-specific-autofilter-on-a-column/32766493#32766493

Comment: Since my examples above have different values in the seperate columns the syntax just duplicates the worksheet....                    var rows = ws2.Cells
                                .GroupBy(cell => cell.Start.Row)
                                //.Skip(1) //Exclude header
                                .Select(cg => cg.Select(c => c.Value).ToArray())
                                .Distinct(new ArrayComparer())
                                .ToArray();